# Apache Superset permissions issue upload csv

Tags: apache-superset

Tried to upload a csv on superset installed in centos7. Gives  an error message "erro no 13 permission denied on  /app/superset/app/

Comment: Created folder with /app/superset/app.  gives back same error message. Forum has one solution on running with sudo but that also does not work

Answer (score 0):

chmod -R incubator-superset  gave the necessary permissions recursively to folder-subfolder-files. 
 Not needed to restart the app as well

Answer (score -1):

Which database are you trying to upload the CSV to? You cannot upload CSVs to the "main" or "examples" databases, to the best of my recollection. You'd have to connect another database of your own.

Once you have a viable database selected, you have to edit the database and check the `Allow Csv Upload` box, as well as make some changes in the `Extra` section as per the instructions you see right below that input.